# Reading Excel data and showing in table format in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, import-from-excel

I am using MVC3. I want to read data from Excel sheet which will be saved inside one folder of my application. Row by row I have to validate the data. Finally have to show the same in tabular form on view. If there are validation problems then those cells should have background color red.

So, I am want solution to read data from Excel and showing in tabular form on view as told. What features I can use for this in my MVC application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Open XML SD](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)K or [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to do this. If using old excel .xls  I would recommend [using OLE DB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB)